# Force site-wide HTTPS, but force HTTP in specific directory

Tags: .htaccess, https, url-rewriting

I've looked but can't find the answer I need - or that works for me.
I have a websites that I force https via htaccess.
There is 1 specific directory that must be http (cannot be https).

I have this in my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/excluded_directory/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This does not force non-https in the "excluded_directory".
I have also tried adding a second htaccess in the "excluded_directory" but to no avail.
Can someone help me to get this right?

Answer (score 0):

To redirect a specific directory urls from `https` to `http` you can use the following in your `/dir/.htaccess` :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on

RewriteRule ^/?thisDir/.*$ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a condition statement as well for more options. You'd replace your current rules with this.

```
  <If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/exclude_directory# && %{HTTPS} == 'on'">
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 
  </If>
  <ElseIf "%{REQUEST_URI} !~ m#^/exclude_directory# && %{HTTPS} == 'off'">
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 
  </Else>
```